# ASUS Zenbook - Bootloader doesn't recognize Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios, uefi

I've scoured the internet trying to find a solution to this.

I've a ASUS Zenbook UX430UAR. I am not able to access the BIOS. I believe it's because I had fast-boot enabled when Windows 10 was on this. I then installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it.

Here's the actual problem:

- Device turns on, and boots normally for Ubuntu, but cannot access BIOS (Neither rapidly pressing or pressing and holding F2, F8, DELETE, ESC, etc. have worked)
- Cannot access Windows 10 USB installer, both GPT and MBR formatted drives
- Installed Windows 10 on the SSD by removing it separately and installing it to a separate computer
- Windows 10 does not load. I can access an Ubuntu 20.04 USB installer and re-install Ubuntu to the USB drive.

Things I've tried:

- Taking apart the laptop; I can't find the CMOS battery no matter where I look. I've read that newer laptops just hold a residual charge. I've disconnected the main battery for several minutes and held the power button in an attempt to discharge the motherboard to reset my NVRAM to access my BIOS. No luck.
- Installing Windows 10 to the SSD using a different computer. No luck. Does not even show up as a boot option with `efibootmgr` using the Ubuntu USB installer (`Try Ubuntu`).

Things that WORK:

- Booting and Installing from Ubuntu 20.04 USB
- Booting from Ubuntu 20.04 SSD

Can't access my BIOs for boot options, but can individually access Ubuntu but not Windows 10!

I'm trying to install Windows 10, but it's been a struggle. If there's something I can do to fix this, whether it's some kind of hardware trick or a setting from reinstalling Ubuntu first, please let me know.